# How to remove all occurrence of character ' in a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

My string is like (passenger's name is Suraj and passenger's contact number is `XXXXXXX672`).
How can I remove the occurrences of ' from the string ?
I tried using

```
comments = comments.replace(/'/g, ' '); and comments = comments.replace(/\'/g, ' ');
```

But they did not work. Please suggest me the needful.

Comment: I just tested out your code in console with your sample string. It is working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/qafy5m0v/

Comment: Are you sure the character in the string is an apostrophe, not a "smart quote"?

Comment: Which one is working first or second ? I tried both but script error is coming.

Comment: @HimanshuShukla what error is coming?

Comment: I have a feeling the character in your string is ` not '. SO is labeling that portion of the string as a code section - which shows you've used ` not '

Comment: Error is [Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list ] and yes it is ' character only as mentioned in the example.

Comment: First I am storing the string in DB, then again I am retrieving it and processing it. This error is occurring at that time. While storing it is not showing any error.

Answer (score 9):

Your code

```
var temp = "passenger's name is Suraj and passenger's contact number is    XXXXXXX672";
var test = temp.replace(/'/g, ' ');
```

Output

```
"passenger s name is Suraj and passenger s contact number is XXXXXXX672"
```

Its working fine.

[image]

Comment: First I am storing the string in DB, then again I am retrieving it and processing it. This error is occurring at that time. While storing it is not showing any error.

Comment: How to remove all occurrence of character ' in a string in Javascript? this is what you asked. if you are running in different problem post that separately.